# Write results into parameters in Python?

Tags: python

How can I write results into the passed parameters (arguments)?

```
### permutation function

def xchg(a, b):
    """ xchg function that does a permution for two integers
    """
    a=a+b
    b=a-b
    a=a-b

a=int(input("Enter a number: "))
b=int(input("Enter another number: "))
xchg(a,b)
print("a= ", a)
print("b= ", b)
```

Comment: You've got the right idea, but your `a` and `b` variables change scope due to the function. Therefore `a` and `b` switch only within the scope of `xchg`. You'd have to return a value and assign that value to a variable if you wanted this to work. For future information, this has to do with mutability of datatypes in python.

Comment: I have preserved the actual question in my edit. It is understandable that you want to describe where you're coming from, but we can see that you're new to Python. But even if we couldn't, it doesn't change the goal that you want to achieve, which is why the information is irrelevant.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. "Where you're coming from" in this case is metaphorical - phant0m really means "describing your motivation and background".

Comment: @phant0m sorry for misunderstand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that what you're trying to do is ***not*** possible.

In Python, there are values and there are names (variables).

An assignment makes a name *refer* to a value. It follows, that the same value can have multiple names.

Function parameters are names, that are *local* to that function. Assigning to them *cannot* make a different name magically refer to a different value. All it does is "bind" the local name to a different value.

Now, there are mutable values, and there are immutable values. Remember, different names can refer to the same value. If you *change* the value, rather than bind a name to a different value, all other names that are bound to that value will see the change, too.

Comment: i think this how should be:
`### permutation function
def xchg(a, b):
    """ xchg function that does a permution for two integers
    """
    a=a+b
    b=a-b
    a=a-b
    return a, b
a=int(input("Enter a number: "))
b=int(input("Enter another number: "))
a,b=xchg(a,b)
print("a= ", a)
print("b= ", b)`

Comment: `def xchg(a, b): return b, a` In Pyhton there is not need for the C/assembler style im-place swap pattern!

Comment: @Ber Is that directed at me or he OP?

Comment: @phant0m That was at no one in particular, just pointing out a simpler version.

Answer (score 8):

If you're learning Python, you should learn how to write Python, not learn how to write C or Java in Python.

In Python, there is no point in doing this. Much better:

```
b, a = a, b
```

Comment: i know this, i just want to write a function exemple

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def xchg(a, b):
    return b, a
```

and then later:

```
a, b = xchg(a, b)
```